# custom admin thumbnail for videos, not getting post's id?

Tags: attachments, id, icon

In the attachments edit page i'm trying to use the selected thumbnail instead of the default icon. 99% of the way there but i can't get the attachment's id into the function.

Am i missing something obvious? Help appreciated! Dc.

```
function set_attachments_icon($icon, $mime = null, $post_id){
    $vars = get_defined_vars();
    print_r($vars);

    echo " ??".$icon."?? ".$post->id.' '.$post_id.'  ?? id not getting picked up?';

    $thumb_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'dsv_thumbnail_id', true);

    if($thumb_id!=''){
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id );
        $icon =  $image_attributes[0];
    }

    return $icon;
}

add_filter('wp_mime_type_icon', 'set_attachments_icon');
apply_filters( 'wp_mime_type_icon', $icon, $mime, $post_id );
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need the apply_filters below.  That is called directly from the wp_mime_type_icon() function already.

The issue is that your add_filter() call is missing the $accepted_args parameter.  The add_filter() function has the following construct:

```
add_filter($tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1)
```

So the $accepted_args is 1 by default.  Because of this, only the first argument of $icon gets passed into your function.  You need to use the following code when adding your filter:

```
add_filter('wp_mime_type_icon', 'set_attachments_icon', 10, 3);
```

Comment: ok - think i spoke too soon. All the data seems to be correct now but its not changing the icon (the src is empty). Here's the spitout. Array ( [icon] => http://sandbox.modernactivity.co.uk/waspface_wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/PrairieMilk_H264-8-still-150x84.jpg [mime] => video/mp4 [post_id] => 8 [thumb_id] => 16 [image_attributes] => Array ( [0] => http://sandbox.modernactivity.co.uk/waspface_wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/PrairieMilk_H264-8-still-150x84.jpg [1] => 150 [2] => 84 [3] => 1 ) )

Comment: It may be because you're using $post->ID instead of $post_id as the get_post_meta() parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The apply_filters call is as follows:

```
apply_filters( 'wp_mime_type_icon', $icon, $mime, $post_id ); // Last arg is 0 if function pass mime type.
```

It looks like this is passing the post_id directly and not the post object. That sure would do it! Try this code instead (note that I didn't try it, we're just shooting from the hip here)

```
function set_attachments_icon($icon, $mime, $post_id){
    if (!$post_id) return $icon;
    $thumb_id = get_post_meta($post_id,'dsv_thumbnail_id', true);
    if($thumb_id){
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id );
        $icon = $image_attributes[0];
    }
    return $icon;
}
add_filter('wp_mime_type_icon', 'set_attachments_icon', 10, 3);
```

For me, however, this didn't get hit in the chain because of `image_downsize` in wp-includes/media.php line 607. You can intercept this to do what you need to do too.

```
function set_attachments_downsize($return, $attachment_id, $size){
    if ( $size == 'thumbnail' && $thumb_id = get_post_meta($attachment_id,'dsv_thumbnail_id', true) ) {
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id );
        return $image_attributes[0];
    }
    return $return;
}
add_filter('image_downsize', 'set_attachments_downsize', 10, 3);
```

Cheers~

Comment: thanks Matthew - updated the above with the apply_filters but no joy.

Comment: Ok, I added more code to my post. Try that out and let me know! We'll get this sorted

Comment: agh - still not coming through. How annoying. Do we not need the apply filters for your new code?

Comment: And your post has the custom meta dsv_thumbnail_id set?

Comment: yeh - which i can't get without the post or attachments id ;-/

Comment: Ok, let's start from the beginning then because I think we're spiraling out of control. Ultimately, you're trying to change the thumbnail showed on the **attachment** edit page in wp-admin, right? e.g. /wp-admin/media.php?attachment_id=123&action=edit

Comment: yep (and once this is working hopefully the video icons throughout, i.e. /wp-admin/upload.php)

Comment: Ok one more question -- what is the meta key dsv_thumbnail_id attached to? The image or the post to which the image is attached?

Comment: its the ID of the chosen image that represents the video...

Comment: Sorry, I mean is the custom meta dsv_thumbnail_id _set_ on the edit media page, or is it _set_ on an edit post/page/custom post type page? So is that meta key owned by the attachment, a post, a page, or a custom post type?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2295/discussion-between-matthew-boynes-and-daniel-crabbe)